# Integration of a singly linked tail queue support in C++

Tags: c++, c, queue

I'm currently trying to integrate an ASN.1 decoder code written in C to the C++ Builder XE6 environment. I've encountered some problems while using the Singly linked tail queue support provided by the library, with the following call :

```
asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_t *wc;
while((wc = TQ_REMOVE(&(wx->chunks), next)))
    asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_free(wc);
```

The error that I get is :

**member reference type 'int' is not a pointer**

The definitions of asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_t (wc) and asn1p_wsyntx_t (wx) are :

```
typedef struct asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_s {
    enum {
        WC_LITERAL,
        WC_WHITESPACE,
        WC_FIELD,
        WC_OPTIONALGROUP
    } type;
    /*
     * WC_LITERAL -> {token}
     * WC_WHITESPACE -> {token}
     * WC_FIELD -> {token}
     * WC_OPTIONALGROUP -> {syntax}
     */
    union {
        char *token;
        struct asn1p_wsyntx_s *syntax;
    } content;

    TQ_ENTRY(struct asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_s) next;
} asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_t;

typedef struct asn1p_wsyntx_s {

    TQ_HEAD(struct asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_s) chunks;

} asn1p_wsyntx_t;
```

The code of the Singly linked tail is this one :

```
#define TQ_HEAD(type)                   \
    struct {                    \
        type *tq_head;              \
        type**tq_tail;              \
    }

#define TQ_MOVE(to, from)   do {            \
    if(&(TQ_FIRST(from)) == (from)->tq_tail) {  \
        TQ_INIT(to);                \
    } else {                    \
        (to)->tq_head = (from)->tq_head;    \
        (to)->tq_tail = (from)->tq_tail;    \
    }                       \
    TQ_INIT(from);                  \
    } while(0)

#define TQ_ENTRY(type)                  \
    struct {                    \
        type *tq_next;              \
    }

#define TQ_FIRST(headp)     ((headp)->tq_head)
#define TQ_NEXT(el, field)  ((el)->field.tq_next)

#define TQ_INIT(head) do {              \
    TQ_FIRST((head)) = 0;               \
    (head)->tq_tail = &TQ_FIRST((head));        \
    } while(0)

#define TQ_FOR(var, head, field)            \
    for((var) = TQ_FIRST((head));           \
        (var); (var) = TQ_NEXT((var), field))

/* MSVC does not have decltype(), cannot prevent side effects! */
#define TQ_ADD(head, xel, field) do {           \
    decltype(xel) __el = (xel);         \
    assert(TQ_NEXT((__el), field) == 0);        \
        *(head)->tq_tail = (__el);          \
        (head)->tq_tail = &TQ_NEXT((__el), field);  \
    } while(0)

#define TQ_CONCAT(head1, head2, field) do {     \
    if(TQ_FIRST(head2)) {               \
        *(head1)->tq_tail = (head2)->tq_head;   \
        (head1)->tq_tail = (head2)->tq_tail;    \
        TQ_INIT(head2);             \
    }                       \
    } while(0)

/*
 * Remove the first element and return it.
 */
#define TQ_REMOVE(head, field)  ({          \
    auto __fel = TQ_FIRST((head));          \
    if(__fel == 0                   \
    || (TQ_FIRST((head)) = TQ_NEXT(__fel, field))   \
        == 0) {                 \
        (head)->tq_tail = &TQ_FIRST((head));    \
    } else {                    \
        TQ_NEXT(__fel, field) = 0;      \
    }                       \
    __fel; })
```

I've tried different casts but without success.

Thank you for your help !

EDIT :

Here is the code that I get for this call once preprocessed :

```
 asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_t *wc;
  while((wc = ({ auto __fel = (((&(wx->chunks)))->tq_head); if(__fel == 0 ||
 ((((&(wx->chunks)))->tq_head) = ((__fel)->next.tq_next)) == 0) 
  { (&(wx->chunks))->tq_tail = &(((&(wx->chunks)))->tq_head); } 
else { ((__fel)->next.tq_next) = 0; } __fel; })))
   asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_free(wc);
```

Comment: Why are you using macros all over the place instead of templates?

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear enough, sorry about that. This is a C code that I'm provided, and I want to make it work in C++ Builder XE6.

Comment: `/* MSVC does not have decltype(), cannot prevent side effects! */` What version of MSVC are you targeting, because 11 and 12 both support `decltype`

Comment: You should show the declaration of `asn1p_wsyntx_chunk_t`. Otherwise, we're all shooting in the dark.

Comment: I don't have much information about it, but this code may be old. I'm not targeting MSVC but C++ Builder XE6.

Comment: Not obvious to me what's wrong. I would recommend looking at the code after it's been run through the preprocessor. This is supported by most compilers. (With gcc, for example, you can do that with the `-E` option.) Then, if it's not obvious what's wrong, take the preprocessed output, remove all the lines starting with # and run it back through the compiler again so that you can pinpoint exactly what the code looks like at the point where it's failing.

Comment: Thank you for you help, I'm looking for how to do that with C++ Builder

Comment: After doing what you suggested, it seems that the problem comes from "auto", which is giving the type "int" to __fel, when it should be a pointer.